# Opening a file in a folder in Python?

Tags: python, text, copy, directory

I want to open a file to write to.

```
with open(oname.text , 'w') as f:
```

and now I want  to write the files in a folder `"Playlist"`

I know that I have to use `os.path` But I do not know how to use it

ty all

Comment: `os.chdir('Playlist')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
path = os.path.join('Playlist', oname.text)
with open(path, 'w') as f:
    ...
```

If you're not sure if the `'Playlist'` subdir of the current directory already exists, prefix that with:

```
if not os.path.isdir('Playlist'):
    if os.path.exists('Playlist'):
        raise RuntimeError('Playlist exists and is a file, now what?!')
    os.mkdir('Playlist')
```

This raises an exception if `'Playlist'` does exist but as a file, not a directory -- handle this anomalous case as you wish, but unless you remove or rename the file, you're not going to be able to have it as a directory as well!

Use `os.makedirs` instead of `os.mkdir` if the path you desire has multiple levels of directories, e.g `Play/List/Whatever` (you could use it anyway just in case).

Answer (score 0):

You could change the current working directory using `os.chdir` function.

```
os.chdir('Playlist')
with open(oname.text , 'w') as f:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `with` statement and `os.path.join` method

```
dir_path =  "/home/Playlist"
file_path = os.path.join('dir_path, "oname.txt")
content = """ Some content..."""
with open(file_path, 'wb') as fp:
    fp.write(content)
```

OR

```
fp = open(file_path, "wb"):
fp.write(content)
fp.close()
```